# Convert DateTime in to number

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a column in my df that has datetime, such as '21:56:02', how is the best way to convert that in to an indentical numeric format, so '215602'?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove `:`

```
a = '21:56:02'
print(a.replace(':',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

If "21:56:02" is a string, then:

```
date = "21:56:02"
int_date = int(date.replace(":", ""))
```

Or for column:

```
date_col.str.replace(":", "").astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_datetime`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": [ '21:56:02',  '20:56:02', '19:56:02']})
print(  pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.strftime("%H%M%S") )
```

**Output:**

```
0    215602
1    205602
2    195602
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

*If you need as int object*

```
print(  pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]).dt.strftime("%H%M%S").astype(int) )
```